# CQFL RAW method parameters losing their default NULL values in generated SQL

Tags: codefluent

When creating a RAW CFQL method, I noticed the declaration of the parameters are losing their default NULL values compared to a traditional SEARCH method.

The generated procedure would thus not accept any null argument.
Typically I would like to have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_AdvancedSearch]
(
 @townIds [nvarchar] (max) = NULL,
 @townLabel [nvarchar] (256) = NULL
)
```

instead of

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[User_AdvancedSearch]
(
 @townIds [nvarchar] (max),
 @townLabel [nvarchar] (256)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @paramlist nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql=
'SELECT 1,2'
SELECT @paramlist = 'townIds nvarchar (256), 
    @townLabel nvarchar (256)'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
RETURN
```

The example used here is as follow

```
<cf:method name="AdvancedSearch">
      <cf:body text="RAW(string[] townIds, string townLabel)  " rawText="DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @paramlist nvarchar(max)&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;SELECT @sql=&#xD;&#xA;'SELECT 1,2'&#xD;&#xA;SELECT @paramlist = 'townIds nvarchar (256), &#xD;&#xA;    @townLabel nvarchar (256)'&#xD;&#xA;EXEC sp_executesql @sql&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" language="tsql" />
    </cf:method>
```

1 - **How can I have my parameter to default to NULL in a RAW method ?**

Also I noticed that property giving the return type (Return Type Name) doesn't seem to be taken into account. The method generated returns *void* instead of the selected type and is located in the **Entity** class instead of the **EntityCollection** class.

I have read in this link [1](https://blog.codefluententities.com/2014/07/03/cfql-raw-methods/) that *For syntax: RAW(arguments). You have to specify the return type in the property grid*

The method generated doesn't take into account this property and returns void as follow.

```
public static void AdvancedSearch(string[] townIds, string townLabel)
        {
            if ((townLabel == default(string)))
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("townLabel");
            }
            CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence persistence = CodeFluentContext.Get(WcfServices.Model.Constants.WcfServices_ModelStoreName).Persistence;
            persistence.CreateStoredProcedureCommand(null, "User", "AdvancedSearch");
            persistence.AddParameter("@townIds", townIds);
            persistence.AddParameter("@townLabel", townLabel);
            System.Data.IDataReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                persistence.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((reader != null))
                {
                    reader.Dispose();
                }
                persistence.CompleteCommand();
            }
        }
```

2 - **How can I have the RAW CFQL procedure to return according type ?**

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a method `SEARCH() RAW`:

```
<cf:method name="SearchRaw" body="SEARCH(string text1, string text2) RAW" rawBody="SELECT @text1" />
```

If you still want to create a method `RAW`, you need to set parameters to be nullable and to specify the return type:

```
<cf:method name="SearchRaw" body="RAW(string text1, string text2)" rawBody="SELECT 1" returnTypeName="{0}.CustomerCollection">
  <cf:parameter name="text1" nullable="true" />
  <cf:parameter name="text" nullable="true" />
</cf:method>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works; but any time I save the surface, the underlying XML gets changed. In particular instead of having body and rawBody attributes, I end up with text and rawText attributes like in my example. The parameters tag gets stripped out as well.

Comment: Ok, once the RAW procedure is generated, going into properties > parameters > add and setting correct values would make the trick, despite the syntax is not excatly the same;